# BizTalk SQL Generate MetaData Failure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm currently trying to setup adapter metadata for an SQL adapter in BizTalk through the add generated items (add adapter metadata) wizard but the wizard keeps failing/disappearing.

I can get as far as the Select the type of statement selection.
I choose stored procedure, hit next then the wizard just disappears.

I've checked event viewer but I can't see any related events, I can't see any hidden popups etc. so I'm at a loss.

I am using BizTalk Server 2013 R2 (Standard), with Microsoft SQL 2014 Standard.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 for development with the BizTalk Dev kit.
My dev machine is currently running Windows 10 Pro.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix this? I did have a bit of a Google but I couldn't see anything unfortunately.

Comment: Did you manage to solve htis issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much playing around, I finally found the fix.

I'd uninstalled Visual Studio, BizTalk, and anything to do with SQL Server.
Then I'd installed again in the below order:-

1. Visual Studio 2013
2. Update 5
3. Checked for updates
4. SQL Server 2014
5. Checked for updates
6. BizTalk 2013 R2
7. Checked for updates

That looks to have done it for me.